# what do t after postgres sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

plese anyone tell me what the meaning of "t" after this postgres Sql query.

const query = `select jsonb_agg(single_day) as availability from (select jsonb_build_object('day', day, 'hours_format', min(hours_format),'time_array', jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('start_time', start_time, 'end_time', end_time) order by start_time ASC)) as single_day from provider_availability where user_id = ${user_id} group by day) t`,

Comment: It's a table alias. I.e. a name for the subquery.

Comment: It's a [table alias](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLE-ALIASES)

Answer (score 2):

`t` is a table alias for the subquery in the FROM clause, which allows you to then reference that table alias in other clauses (e.g WHERE t.start_time = [time]). Just using the alias name on its own immediately after the closing bracket of the subquery is shorthand for writing `AS t`.